# Fetching ElastiCache Tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-elasticache, boto3

I am trying to fetch ElastiCache Tags using Boto3 and Python. In boto3, there is a function called- list_tags_for_resource(). But, the problem I am facing is, how to find the resource name. I am using the following code:

```
from boto3.session import Session

sess = Session(aws_access_key_id=id,aws_secret_access_key=key)
conn = sess.client(service_name='elasticache', region_name='us-east-1')
arn="arn:aws:elasticache:us-east-1:123456:cluster:name_of_cluster"
print conn.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=name)
```

This is giving the following error :

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the ListTagsForResource operation: Unauthorized call. Please check the region or customer id
```

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that the credentials you are supplying are incorrect.  Double-check your access key and secret key.

Comment: The credentials are fine. Basically, the problem is how to get the ResourceName?

Comment: I'm not sure that's true.  I tried a test case with an invalid ARN and got CacheClusterNotFound error rather than the error you are getting.  However, its possible that if you are constructing the ARN without a valid account id (what you are showing as 123456 in your example) you could get this error.  Are you using your correct account ID?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a way to get the ARN of a Cache Cluster through the AWS API. You just have to guess it (like you did in your example). If your creds are fine, you may not have substituted the right account number in the ARN. Double-check that the `123456` part of the ARN has the correct account number.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the ReadOnlyAccess managed policy, you will not be able to list tags for elasticache. Ensure that your user has `elasticache:ListTagsForResource` explicitly set in their policy. Amazon does not currently include that permission in their ReadOnlyAccess policy. A policy that allows viewing elasticache tags would look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2015-06-26",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticache:ListTagsForResource"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I believe this should be part of the ReadOnlyAccess policy,and opened a ticket with Amazon. This was their response:

> You raise a valid point regarding "elasticache:ListTagsForResource" not being included in the AWS supplied "ReadOnlyAccess" managed policy.  We can't very well call it read only when it doesn't allow someone to list tags on a named resource in my opinion. Therefore, I have opened an internal ticket with the team who controls these managed policies; requesting that the API "elasticache:ListTagsForResource" be added to "ReadOnlyAccess".

Answer (score 0):

Well the script posted has some problems.
Your passing the variable 'name' which isn't defined. 
I think you mean arn and maybe there are other ways to do it but I define region_name in session rather than client.
Try something like this out.

```
session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1',aws_access_key_id=id,aws_secret_access_key=key)
client = session.client("elasticache")
arn = "arn:aws:elasticache:us-east-1:1234567889:cluster:rand57hzn577a78-0001-001"
client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=arn)
```